# Fibonacci sequence and golden ratio

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I have recently read about the numerous occurrences of the golden ratio and Fibonacci numbers in nature. I have read that it occurs in everything from shells to plants and that the rectangle that is most aesthetically pleasing has its sides in this ratio aswell. Are these just coincidences or is there a reason that it occurs so often?

Comment: The occurrences of the golden ratio in nature are often coincidences, or people imposing such a ratio where it doesn't actually exist.  It is pure numerological hogwash.  As to the Fibonacci sequence showing up in nature, [Vi Hart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXIMUkSXX0) has a good explanation of why me might expect the Fibonacci numbers to show up in plant morphology (the second video in the series, in particular, I think is where it is addressed).  Though, again, I think it is mostly people fishing for significance.

Comment: At any rate, I've voted to close this question as "Primarily Opinion Based."

Comment: The true reason is that people *want* to see it in nature. https://vimeo.com/88132964

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read the book [The Mathematics of Harmony](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Mathematics_of_Harmony.html?id=K6fac9RxXREC). I am sure you can find interesting answers for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take ten random numbers in range $[0,1]$, such as ten measurements on the human body or on the Parthenon.

Like

$$0.699, 0.637, 0.407, 0.599, 0.024, 0.998, 0.425, 0.248, 0.460, 0.616.$$

Form all pairwise ratios and look for $\phi$:

$$1.000, 1.724, 0.011, 1.475, 1.067, 1.103, 1.416, 1.101, 0.702, 0.077\\
0.580, 1.000, 0.007, 0.856, 0.619, 0.640, 0.821, 0.639, 0.407, 0.045\\
87.766, 151.292, 1.000, 129.477, 93.606, 96.849, 124.241, 96.613, 61.643, 6.801\\
0.678, 1.168, 0.008, 1.000, 0.723, 0.748, 0.960, 0.746, 0.476, 0.053\\
0.938, \color{red}{1.616}, 0.011, 1.383, 1.000, 1.035, 1.327, 1.032, 0.659, 0.073\\
0.906, 1.562, 0.010, 1.337, 0.967, 1.000, 1.283, 0.998, 0.636, 0.070\\
0.706, 1.218, 0.008, 1.042, 0.753, 0.780, 1.000, 0.778, 0.496, 0.055\\
0.908, 1.566, 0.010, 1.340, 0.969, 1.002, 1.286, 1.000, 0.638, 0.070\\
1.424, 2.454, 0.016, 2.100, 1.519, 1.571, 2.015, 1.567, 1.000, 0.110\\
12.905, 22.246, 0.147, 19.039, 13.764, 14.241, 18.269, 14.206, 9.064, 1.000
$$

It's there !

Comment: So its not actually anything special just people trying to see something that isnt there?

Comment: @A.Darwish: that's my opnion.